# Javascript variable changes in Internet Explorer unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Let us start with the Javascript-code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var parentWindowLocation = '';

// closes the popop of the search when the parent is closed
window.onload = function() {
    parentWindowLocation = window.opener.location;

    if (window.opener != null) {
        setInterval("checkParentExists()", 5000);
    }
}

function checkParentExists() {
    try {
        alert(window.opener.location);
        alert(parentWindowLocation);
        if (window.opener == null || window.opener.closed) {
            window.close();
        } else {
            if (parentWindowLocation != window.opener.location) { window.close(); }
        }
    } catch (e) { window.close(); }
}
</script>
```

The code above is specified in a popup. The popup should close itself when the parent is closed or if the URL of the parent has changed.
This works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but not in Internet Explorer.

I've added the two *alerts* in *checkParentExists()* to see what happened in Internet Explorer.
I noticed that when the parent changes to a different URL (so window.opener.location changes) the variable parentWindowLocation is also set to the new URL of the parent! I only set the variable in window.onload so what happened?

Comment: Maybe you could you try setting it to window.location.href instead of just window.location?

Comment: Don't use `setInterval` this way, but pass it a function reference, like `setInterval(checkParentExists, 5000);`. And don't use global variables, as they might be changed by others.

Comment: instead of using `window.onload = function()` try using the onLoad attribute with body tag `<body onload="someFunc()">`

Comment: Also in IE i believe the opener no longer exists if the location of the parent window changed

Comment: @anu: No, that does the same and it is not recommended to mix HTML markup with JavaScript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "location" object is, well, an object.  When you convert it to a string, you get something made from the properties of the object, but it's *not* a string. Thus, your variable can still refer to the "location" object, but the value can change.

If you set your variable to `window.opener.location.href` instead, you'll get a string.  You could also try this:

```
     parentWindowLocation = window.opener.location + '';
```

which will also force it to be "captured" as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in the parent:

```
var childWin;
window.onbeforeunload=function() {
  try {
    if (childWin && !childWin.closed()) childWin.close();
  }
  catch(e) {}
}
.
.
.
childWin=window.open(....);
```